# Bot Framework needs to be hosted?

Tags: botframework

Do I need to have my Bot hosted in order to use the embeded web chat option using the Iframe? 
(https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/botme?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE'>)

I want to do some test with localhost and with the embed. Mostly a demo.

Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem I keep getting is  "POST https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations 403 (Forbidden)" Im using ngrok to configure the endpoint and I run the bot using C# (Tried nodejs same result). I don't know if I'm missing something. On emulator it works great.

Comment: Hi, fixed the problem by using  the Secret Key provided in Direct Line instead of the one provided in web chat. Don't know why but it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If your bot is already [registered](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/gettingstarted.html#registering) in [Dev Portal](https://dev.botframework.com) and endpoint is already set then the easiest way to test embed chat locally without having any web-site is just to paste this as URL on any browser:

```
data:text/html, <iframe style="height:480px; width:400px" src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/botme?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE'></iframe>
```

Yeah, it may look strange, but just paste it on browser's address bar and press `Enter`. Another quick option is to put that iframe to your bot's `default.htm` page (which should exist on your solution) so when you run the project and browser is automatically open, you'll see the embed chat control there.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to demo is to use [the bot framework emulator](https://emulator.botframework.com/), https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator , you can run your bot code locally.

The emulator looks the same as the web chat.

If you want to use the real web chat you can still host your bot locally but provide a temporary public url to the bot framework using `ngrok`. So, you should register your bot and set the bot url obtained form `ngrok`, get the secret and use it in your web chat.

As alternative you can use one of free hosting to host your bot code. For NodeJs version you can use services like `heroku`.

Comment: Actually I would like to disagree with the statement that "The emulator looks the same as the web chat." . The embed chat looks a little bit different and is more buggy (especially while showing Cards and attachments)

Comment: You may connect https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat to the emulator (some programming work are required), so you get exact local web chat.

Comment: I actually registered the bot  used ngrok and provided the link on messaging endpoint it works well on the site to, example (https://dev.botframework.com/bots?id=botme) 
but when I use the embed (or just the source and I get  POST https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations 403 (Forbidden)   ) 
Used newly generated secret code. 
Does the bot have to be published? I keep thinking I'm missing something..

Comment: You bot is not needed to be published. To access the directline API you should use bearer token, not the secret. Check the authentication section in the documentation.